# Forecast using time and cluster as groups

Tags: r, forecasting

I'm a relative newbie with R and I'm trying to figure out the R code to generate a table of forecast data that I can export to a CSV for multiple variables grouped by different slices.

My data looks like this:

```
Time          Cluster           X1          X2          X3          ...
2018-04-21       A              10          53          23          ...
2018-04-21       B              65          34          79          ...
2018-04-22       A              35          80          76          ...
2018-04-22       B              12          68          34          ...
```

I'd like to get a forecast by date per cluster for each X value in the table. The end goal is to combine all the forecasted values into a CSV for import into a DB. My initial dataset has 7 different cluster values and about 3 months of daily data. There are about 6 different values that need forecasts. I can (and have) done this fairly easily in Excel, but the requirement going forward is R to a CSV to a DB.

Thanks in advance!

Brandon~

Comment: Please share how you did it in Excel so that we see the algorithm that you want.

Comment: In Excel, I pull the data and use the FORECAST formula to return the results for future dates. So basically, it's a HW with trend and seasonality. I have it set to run a 12 month forecast everytime I update with new data. I'd like to get forecast data for: Linear trend, Simple Moving Average, HW, and ARIMA. Then compare the accuracy of each in order to use the best model.